# How to change an object type in java

Tags: java, class, object

I am trying to change an object to another similar object.
Both objects are sub classes of the class Player it is originally type Human and I am trying to change it to type EasyCompAI it remains type Human. When i initialize p2 it is Player p2= new Human(); which is OK. I Tried:

```
Player p2=new Human(2,'2');
p2 = null; 
p2 = new EasyCompAI(2, '2');
```

but when I do

```
gui.getBoardPanel().getP2().getClass();
```

I get Human

thank you for your time and help if more context is needed I will gladly add more.

Comment: I think you are confusing the terms type and class. Regardless, you can't change an object's class to another, i.e., Human to EasyCompAI. 

I just saw your edit. p2 starts off assigned to a Human, and then you assign it to an EasyCompyAI. Without seeing your code, I'm guessing that you didn't update gui after reassigning p2.

Comment: What do you mean by updating my GUI. So when I created my p2 even though it was a Player Object by Setting it to the subclass Human I can't change it to the other subclass EasCompAI? Do you have any suggestions on how I can get the results I want?

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to answer this question unless you post some actual code - read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Btw are you sure you're changing the value in your "BoardPanel", not just random variable somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are updating the boardPanel's p2 property? Because when you do you `Player p2 = new Human(2, '2,')`, you are creating a new variable. You need to save it in the boardsPanel object.

Answer (score 1):

**Variables and instances**

First, probably you are confusing variables and object instances.

If you create a variable (or an attribute), it may contain references to objects of the same class of the variable or any of its subclasses.

```
// this variable may contain instances of Player or any Player subclass
Player player;
```

You may assign to the variable an object instance of one of the subclasses. For instance, you may assign to the above player variable an instance of Person. Then, when you print the class of the object, Java will show the correct type.

```
player = new Human( 2, "2");
System.out.println(player.getClass());

// The output is "class example.Human"
```

You may assign to the variable other object. After you assign other object, if you print again the class of the object, Java will show the correct type all the time.

```
player = new AIPlayer( 2, "2");
System.out.println(player.getClass());

// The output is "class example.AIPlayer"
```

In Java, you cannot change the class (the type) of an object. That is not possible. You may assign objects of different classes to the same variable. Naturally, you can only assign objects of the same class of the variable or any of its subclasses.

---

**In your program...**

Probably you have an error in your program.

Note that your example code mentions a variable, probably in the constructor or any other method of a `BoardPanel` class

```
Player p2=new Human(2,'2');

// this is unnecessary
// p2 = null; 

p2 = new EasyCompAI(2, '2');
```

Later, you are trying to get the value of an attribute (not a variable)

```
gui.getBoardPanel().getP2().getClass();
```

Remember that variables and attributes are not the same. For instance, in the following class, the `p2` attribute in the class and the `p2` variable in the method are different.

```
class Example {

   Player p2;   // attribute

   public void example() {
      Player p2;    // variable
   }

}
```